# What is the max number of websites / virtual directories one can host on IIS?

Tags: iis

Can someone tell me the maximum number of websites / virtual directories I can host on a single IIS?

Is there's a difference between IIS 6 and IIS 7?

Comment: Does this belong on serverfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you should be more worried about server performance and connection limitations that the number of websites you can host.

I'd say your machine will collapse before you are able to max out the number, but I don't believe there is a hard limit.

Comment: I'm not asking if it makes scenes or not.  I just want to know if there's a hard number.

Comment: Of which I said there is no hard limit